# Forcing Mathematica's Integrate to give more general answers

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I have a simple gaussian integral:  $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dx\:e^{i\alpha x^2}$.

If $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then:

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx\; e^{i \, \alpha x^2} = \sqrt{\frac \pi {-i \alpha}} \qquad \qquad \alpha <0
$$

Now if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ then we obtain the same answer but with different conditions:

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx\; e^{i \, \alpha x^2} = \sqrt{\frac \pi {-i \alpha}} \qquad \qquad Im(\alpha)>0
$$

These can be combined into a simple answer with an OR statement:

$$
\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx\; e^{i \, \alpha x^2} = \sqrt{\frac \pi {-i \alpha}} \qquad \qquad Im(\alpha)=0 \, \& \, Re(\alpha) <0 \quad|| \quad Im(\alpha)>0
$$

When I I ask Mathematica to solve this for me

```
Integrate[E^(I x^2 a), {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

Mathematica returns **only one** of these cases:

```
ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[π]/Sqrt[-I a], Im[a] > 0]
```

I have tried specifying $Im(\alpha)\geq 0$ in the Assumptions but Mathematica disregards this and gives the same result. It can of course find the answer for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ but it cannot seem to give a *fully general* answer where both conditions are present.

Comment: Where did this integral come up?

Answer (score 7):

If $\alpha$ is complex, then yes,  The imaginary part of alpha should be **strictly** greater than zero.  If $\alpha$ is real, does it converge?  If you complete the contour in the complex plane, with a semicircle, and replace $x$ by $z=x+ i y$, I do not see the integral converging along the semicircle.

$\mathbf{UPDATE:}$

Okay, I looked the integral up in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, **Table of Integrals, Series, and Products**, 6$^\textrm{th}$ edition, p. 333.  Looks like the integral for $\alpha$ real converges for $\alpha<0$ but with limits zero to infinity.

$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty e^{-i\lambda x^2} dx = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}} e^{-i\pi/4}, \quad (\lambda>0)$.

We can infer from this (let $w=-x$ $\Rightarrow$ $dw = - dx$)

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\lambda x^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}} e^{-i\pi/4}, \quad (\lambda>0)$.

Replacing $\lambda$ by $-\lambda$ we get the complex conjugate:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\lambda x^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-\lambda}} e^{i\pi/4}, \quad (\lambda<0)$.

Combining these:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\lambda x^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}} e^{ - i\pi \,\textrm{sign }{(\lambda)} /4}, \quad (\lambda \ne 0, \lambda \in \Re)$.

This is consistent with what Mathematica (Version 11.2.0.0, Mac OS X) gives:

```
Assuming[Element[a,Reals],Integrate[Exp[I a x^2],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

returning

```
Sqrt[Pi]/2 (1+ I Sign[a])/Sqrt[Abs[a]]
```

If anybody has an idea how to compute this integral with contour integration (or otherwise) from first principals, that would be interesting!

**Also**, we still haven't answered why Mathematica assumes that $\alpha$ is not real if $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$!

$\mathbf{ADDITIONAL \,\, UPDATE:}$

This will take into account each case, and output the result or indicate if the integral does not converge:

```
q[a_] := Integrate[Exp[I a x^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]; 
integral[a_] := If[Element[a, Reals], Assuming[Element[a, Reals], q[a]], q[a]];
```

Here are a few examples:

[image]

Comment: I don't think Mathematica gave the proper response $\alpha<0$.  If it converges for $\alpha<0$ why not $\alpha>0$. and does it converge?

Comment: I have assumed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so convergence in that sense has not been accounted for.

Comment: Well, I believe Gradshteyn and Ryzhik's listing.  We can then make some substitutions to compute what happens for $\alpha>0$.  Mathematica (ver. 11.2) gives an answer that is consistent.  Obviously, the integral diverges for $\alpha=0$.  Mathematica's result $\rightarrow \infty$ there.

Comment: "Also, we still haven't answered why Mathematica assumes that  is not real if  ∈ ℂ!". This is exactly my problem!

Comment: Agreed!  I've updated my answer to output what we would have liked to have seen for cases when $\alpha$ is real and when $\alpha$ has a nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Ultimately, I think this behaviour needs to be handled at Wolfram level because there is no reason Mathematica cannot considers these cases simultaneously (evidently, it does the individual cases rather well). I think we can probably come up with other MWEs of the same phenomenon.

Comment: I assume Mathematica does not consider conditions on subsets (say Integers, Reals etc.) even if that means a less general answer.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Mathematica assumes all symbols are complex valued, so this is what you get if you don't specify. You can see all the variations by making assumptions:

```
Integrate[E^(I x^2 a), {x, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> #] 
          & /@ {a ∈ Complexes, a ∈ Reals, Im[a] == 0, 
                Im[a] < 0, Im[a] > 0, Re[a] == 0, Im[a] >= 0, a == 0, a < 0}
```

One of these doesn't converge and another is equal to infinity, but they do give the full range of possibilities.